# Kafka Topic-per-Consumer Configuration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, partitioning, kafka-producer-api

I understand that Kafka Consumer Group is load-balanced based on how many partitions exist for a specific topic. So the ideal combination is 1:1 for the number of partitions for a topic and the number of consumers in a consumer group which subscribes to the topic.

I have a scenario where each of my consumer is actually a consumer-group itself (i.e. 1 consumer per group). This mainly due to synchronisation between different databases so that the same data exists. All I am trying to do is run the same job on different environments as soon as the consumer get a message from the producer (broadcast).

For me, I don't believe that partitions/load balancing idea makes any difference. I am going with a topic that has 1 partitions and `n` Replication-Factor (`n` = total consumer groups, or consumer for my case). Does anyone think that I should still implement more than 1 partition for my case? If so, could you please mention why.

P.S. I am using the Producer/Consumer API only my messaging framework needs to have a minimum change/impact to my existing application setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ideal combination is 1:1 for the number of partitions for a topic and the number of consumers in a consumer group

To be more precise, the number of partitions limits the number of consumers in a consumer group (if there are more consumers than partitions, they will just be idle). There can be fewer consumers than partitions. I wouldn't call 1:1 as necessarily ideal, it's the practical limit.

> I am going with a topic that has 1 partitions and n Replication-Factor (n = total consumer groups, or consumer for my case).

I don't see value having replication-factor equal to number of consumer groups. Replication is for resilience, i.e. to prevent data loss if a broker goes down. It doesn't have anything to do with the number of consumers, since each consumer will only ever be consuming from the leader broker for a given partition.

> Does anyone think that I should still implement more than 1 partition for my case? If so, could you please mention why.

Partitioning data is for load distribution, both on the broker side and for parallelism on the consumer side. It's easier to set a higher number of partitions from the start, even if you don't think you need it, than to re-partition data later, if/when you discover you could benefit from it. On the other hand, there's no point setting them too high as they come with their own overheads (e.g. CPU load on the broker).

> P.S. I am not using the Producer/Consumer API since I am not doing Table/Stream related aggregation

Sounds to me you intended to say you're not using Kafka Streams API, since it's Kafka Streams that offers KTable, KStream and aggregations thereon.

Comment: .Yes sorry about the confusing P.S. part - I have updated my question now/

Answer (score 2):

Multiple partitions are useful when you run Kafka in a cluster where the number of brokers is larger than the replication factor. So when you have 5 brokers and a replication of 3 then the 2  additional brokers are not needed. When you have two partitions with a replication of 3 you can divide 2*3 = 6 partitions over 5 brokers.

Only now there is one broker with two partitions while the others have one. So it's not spread evenly. It would be better to have more partitions to get a better spread.

There are other reasons to pick a number of partitions, but there are a lot of articles about this. What I explained is a good rule of thumb to start with.

Comment: So as long as the ordering is not important I should always leverage the partitions?

Comment: Yes and I think I'm pretty conservative with increasing the number of partitions :-)